Shockley Equation in relation to circuit analysis with PNP and NPN transistors
I have been looking online to create a Sqrt(Vin) circuit using analog electronics. I have stumbled across a statement in youtube videos that from the shockley Eq.
Vbe = Vt Ln( Ic/Is )
However from a std google the shockley Eq is given as
Ic = Is exp( (Vbe q / n k t)  - 1 )
From this it seems that Vbe = Vt Ln( Ic/Is ) is incorrect as the +1 has been dropped from the expression. Is this correct and is this eq equally valid for PNP and NPN transistors for my design process?

Look at the terms:
\$I_\text{T} = I_\text{S} \left( e^\frac{V_\text{D}}{n V_\text{T}} - 1 \right)\$
\$V_\text{T} \approx 0.025V\$ at room temperature
\$n \approx \text{ 1~ 2, more like 1 for transistors} \$
So for there to be at least a 10% error the voltage across the diode will have to be less than about 60mV.
A typical diode-connected jellybean transistor (eg. 2N4401) will have a sub-pA current with that little voltage so the equation is very good with the -1 omitted under sensible forward-biased conditions.
This may well not be true with something like a Schottky power diode, but you would not be using that in this application. For example, a 30A RBR10T30ANZ Schottky rectifier would have a forward current more like 20uA with 60mV across it.
The same equation applies for PNP as for NPN, with appropriate signs changed. Of course, Is will be different in general between different transistors of either type.

@ Spehro Pefhany - I suppose it should read VT~25mV at room temperature. Typing error?

@LvW 0.025 Volts = 25mV. But I'll add the units.

@ Spehro Pefhany - no problem with the units. You wrote VD instead of VT. This was my point!

@LvW dang, late night proofreading is non-ideal, thanks,
